# jquery remove parent tr not working in first time

Tags: jquery

On click of delete button, I want to remove parent tr. The problem is when i click on delete, it blinks and doesn't remove the tr on first click and then when i click that delete second time, iut gets removed. Please help

```
$(".adel").on('click', function () {     
    $(this).parents('tr').hide();
});
```

```html
<tr id="rowtr">
    <td></td>
    <td id="rowtd">
        <a id="" class="adel" href=''>
            <img src='del.png'>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: *Please help* - Please show your code

Comment: It looks like it isnt the direct parent and you are first removing the immediate parent. Please paste your code!

Comment: Is your code in a $(document).ready() block

Comment: what does the HTML look like with the button?

Comment: If you use html5 you dont need to use the `href` attribute. Just remove it, or give it # as value. Empty is not allowed for href

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/zuGBY/ check my ans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".adel").on('click', function (e) {     
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/2ZHBC/1/

Answer (score 1):

I expect you are looking to prevent the default actions of `<a>`:

```
$(".adel").on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents("tr").hide();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SsBMC/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".adel").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('tr').hide();
    });
});
```

**[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/r9Kdm/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".adel").on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();     
 $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `a` tag:

```
<a class="adel" href='javascript:void();'><img src='del.png'/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
$(".adel").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parents('tr').hide();
});
```